# Get Countries and related Cities REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have a form in my mobile app for shipping information. I am looking for REST API to get countries and its related cities.

I found only an API:

```
V1/directory/countries
```

How can I get cities for each country ?

Comment: I don't think Magento has such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an online service called GeoDB that does this and more. To your specific question, try the following requests:

**List of all countries**

http://geodb-free-service.wirefreethought.com/v1/geo/countries

**List of cities, filtered for United States, Spain, and France**

http://geodb-free-service.wirefreethought.com/v1/geo/cities?countryCodes=US,ES,FR

For more info and docs, check out the [portal site](http://geodb-cities-api.wirefreethought.com).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://rapidapi.com/marketplace. There are a lot of REST Api to consume, maybe one of them will fit your need.